# ssl certificate setup invalid

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate

I used godaddy ssl certificate to setup secure my angular 6 application. I hosted that in nginx server and setup ssl certificate. after setup my browser shows certificate(invalid) and Your connection to this site is not secure. so i have to proceed it unsafe option.

I used following configuration to setup ssl in nginx and admin.****.com is my sub domain used for host the site.

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/****.com.1.2019.chain.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/***.com.1.key;
    root /var/www/frontend;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name admin.***.com www.admin.*****.com;
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
}
```

Comment: try `listen 443 ssl` and you probably do not need the next listen line, unless you're doing something with IPv6

Comment: I tried. But still it shows same warning

Comment: @Amith is this wildcard certificate or it's specific for this domain? Try this command to check: `openssl x509 -text -noout -in /etc/ssl/certs/****.com.1.2019.chain.crt | grep CN`.  And show output of this: `echo | openssl s_client -servername admin.*****.com -connect admin.*****.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -issuer -subject -dates`

Comment: There's too many unknowns. Where are the ciphers and protocols defined? Is the chain properly included in the crt file? You can take a look here for what you might be missing http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html

Comment: If you don't show enough things (like `openssl s_client` output as requested above), there isn't much to discuss.